# Router link active is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here, I am creating menu bar in my application using angular 2 and angular material. I have created routing between components. I have also provide routeLinkActive to every option on menu bar.

This is my code of menu bar,

```
<mat-nav-list>
        <button mat-button  routerLink='Espace/home' routerLinkActive="active" ><mat-icon>home</mat-icon> Home</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink='Espace/spacesurvey' routerLinkActive='active'>Space Survey</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink='Espace/spaceadmin' routerLinkActive='active'>Space Admin</button>
        <button mat-button >Reports</button>
        <button mat-button >Joint Use</button>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

But when I look at browser, on Home page it is not showing that home is activated.

Suggest me solution.

Comment: You should use `a[mat-list-item]` instead of a button.

Comment: What's your active class?

Comment: Try adding routerLinkActiveOption to exact match , for example
`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the paths in routerLink, use routerLink = "['Escape', 'home']"

do this for all routerLink

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Regarding your answer, you should provide more information about this in order to help the author understand the reasoning behind this change, like the official [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) ;)